# How to upload large files to S3 using presigned URL?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, ioutils

I have been able to upload successully small files ~1kb but when I try uploading larger files > 1Mb I get this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:699)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:711)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1585)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at com.red5.VimeoTechRojoIntegration.uploadFromEFSToS3(VimeoTechRojoIntegration.java:209)
    at com.red5.Red5ProLive$1.run(Red5ProLive.java:128)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

To upload I am suing this code

```
OutputStream out = null;
InputStream in = null;
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(signedURLS3);
    in = new FileInputStream(videoEFSPath);

    System.out.println("establish connection");
    connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"); 


    System.out.println("get output stream");
    out = (OutputStream) connection.getOutputStream();
    System.out.println("copy");
    IOUtils.copyLarge(in,out);
    System.out.println("copy finished");

    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode < 300)
        return "";

    return "{\"error\":\"The upload to S3 failed. AWS server returned response code "+responseCode+"\"}";   
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: How about the AWS SDK? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#upload-object

Comment: @mrblewog using presigned urls is a way how to decouple the application from the direct use of AWS, or provide the upload to a third-party without a direct AWS access (AWS credentials). The app does only a simple PUT to the url. This works with S3 or anything else without the need to adapt the existing code. So, using AWS SDK is not the right solution here.

Answer (score 0):

This should actually work, I am using Apache HTTP Client for this:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity;

...

String presignedUrl = ...
File file = ...

HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(presignedUrl);
httpPut.setEntity(new FileEntity(file));
HttpResponse httpResponsePut = httpClient.execute(httpPut);
if (httpResponsePut.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() >= HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST) {
    log.error("Error uploading file: " + file.getName() + " / " + httpResponsePut);
}
EntityUtils.consume(httpResponsePut.getEntity());
```